# How did Lex Luthor create the monster?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In the film ***Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice (2016)***, Lex Luthor created a monster from General Zod's body and using his own blood.

What was the explanation of the procedure he used?

Answer (score 9):

[Time magazine says that it is left unexplained](http://time.com/4268441/batman-v-superman-ending-monster/):

> The movie shows Lex Luthor mixing his own blood with that of General
>   Zod to create the monster in the Genesis Chamber of the Kryptonian
>   spaceship that crashed in Man of Steel.
>
> For those who skipped *Man of Steel*, **the Genesis Chamber is used to
>   create beings**. By destroying the ship in Man of Steel, Superman
>   (presumably) throws away any chance he had of creating more of his
>   race.
>
> Given the damage to that ship, it’s unclear how Doomsday is created.
>   **The Kryptonian science behind General Zod’s transformation goes
>   largely unexplained in Batman v Superman.**

Comment: Man, i was writing this same answer :)

Comment: Also unexplained - good reasons I might want to watch it.

Comment: What about the deleted scene where the SWAT team comes and finds Luthor in the chamber with (what some suggest is) Darkseid? I would say that is important to understanding how Luthor created Doomsday.

Comment: I haven't seen "Man of Steel" since it was released in theaters, but do we actually see the Genesis Chamber being destroyed? From what I remember we see the Scout Ship crash, but that's it. This is also shown at the beginning of "Batman v Superman", the ship slices through some skycrapers as it crash-lands, but it looks like it stays largly intact. - And when Luthor turns on the ship, the computer says something like "operating at 30-something percent efficency" and I also remember it saying "Genesis Chamber ready to analyze genetic sample".

Answer (score 0):

The ship does say something before Luthor does the thing with the human blood.  I took it to mean  that Luthor in his 'genius' researched the history of Kryptonian cloning / species mixing experiments and discovered a list of prohibited projects, their outcomes, and the override (though it was pretty easy to override wasn't it?).

I don't remember exactly what the computer said.